# NHibernate IQueryable.SingleOrDefault in subquery. Use function predicate without executing

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a `Query`

`SpecialAttributes` is a `IEnumerable`

```
 q = from c in q
     let x = c.SpecialAttributes.Where(a => a.Attribute.Id == id)
                                .Select(z =>  z.AttribValue).SingleOrDefault()
     orderby Convert.ToDateTime(x)
     select c;
```

I need to execute sql query at once.

But in this case each `SingleOrDefault()` will be executed separately of main query.

If count of fetching results will be 100 - `SingleOrDefault()` will be executed 100 times.

How do it in one query, like `FutureSingleOrDefault()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you won't have attributes with the same id in your special attributes collection and that your "SpecialAttribute" class has a reference to the parent object, this may work:

```
q.SelectMany(x => x.SpecialAttributes)
 .Where(x => x.Attribute.Id == id)
 .OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.AttribValue))
 .Select( x => x.Parent )
 .Distinct();
```

I don't know if EF will parse the Convert.ToDateTime() to a proper t-sql statement. If not, you could do it in memory (if the collection is not huge):

```
q.SelectMany(x => x.SpecialAttributes)
 .Where(x => x.Attribute.Id == id)
 .Select( x => new { Parent = x.Parent, Value = x.AttribVale} )
 .Distinct()
 .OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Value))
 .Select(x => x.Parent);
```

Comment: Worked. But there is a small problem. When `x.Parent` would have a empty SpecialAttributes, It does not fall into fetch. I show `x.Parent` at table, and can't skip records which don't have attributes. Need to show all records, including `x.Parent` with empty SpecialAttributes

Comment: A workaround is to add a Union( q.Where(x => x.SpecialAttributes == null )) or something like that. it will be solved with two queries, by far better than the previous select n+1. Anyway, I'll keep thinking about a better approach...

Comment: What about this:
q = from c in q
     let x = (from a in c.SpecialAttributes where a.Attribute.Id == id select new {z.AttribValue}).FirstOrDefault()
     orderby Convert.ToDateTime(x.AttribValue)
     select c;

two things: I changed the code to 100% linq style following http://geekswithblogs.net/SudheersBlog/archive/2009/06/11/132758.aspx and I changed SingleOrDefault() to FirstOrDefault(). I think that last part could do the trick